# What's the best way to display a title screen for a Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing

I have a swing app and I want there to be a title screen that lasts for a few seconds and then transitions to the program. What's the best way to do this? I was thinking a layered pane with a timer, but maybe there's something better?

Comment: Don't do this. Down with splash screens.

Comment: If you do use a splash-screen (and provided there is control over it, e.g. it's not the dumb splash screen image :-) then I would consider (at the minimum) what Outlooking 2010 allows: Closing the app before it finishes loading! -- and the splash screen can also be moved about! However, if the app doesn't *need* the splash-screen to cover loading times, etc, then I'd just axe it entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the JWS based splash, see also the [SplashScreen](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) class.  The AWT based class provides more control over the splash than JWS, but the JWS based splash worked for versions before 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

You might look into the [splash screen](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#206) feature of [Java Web Start](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-webstart/).